# Issue with ffprobe execution within Docker Environment

Tags: ffmpeg, dockerfile, ffprobe, fluent-ffmpeg

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-slim as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/ai_api_builder/

COPY package*.json tsconfig.json /usr/src/ai_api_builder/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install mariadb-client -y && \
    npm install && npm cache clean --force

RUN apt install ffmpeg -y && \
    ffmpeg -version && \
    ffprobe -version
COPY ${REPO_DIR}/ ./

RUN npm run build && mv audio_store node_modules dist/

FROM node:18-slim

# Create and cd into app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/dwt_api_app/dist

# Copy the artifact to the new image
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/dwt_api_builder/dist ./

EXPOSE 3001

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "app.js"]
```

When I build Dockerfile, the step check ffmpeg and ffprobe version worked:

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.4-0+deb12u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
...
ffprobe version 5.1.4-0+deb12u1 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
```

But when I run container, my TypeScript code not work (the metadata return `undefined`):

```
import { ffprobe } from "fluent-ffmpeg";
ffprobe(latestFilePath, async function(err: any, metadata: any) {
    console.log("metadata", metadata);
})
```

When I exec to container and check `ffmpeg -version` and `ffprobe -version`, I got: `bash: ffmpeg: command not found`. And when I check in bin folder, also couldn't find `ffmpeg`. 
I tried it locally (Centos7), not in container, it worked (metadata return an object), and here is ffprobe version

```
ffprobe version 6.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers <b>
```

What step did I do wrong when running the container or is there any difference between debian (in container) and centos 7 (local) that I need to pay attention to? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you install ffmpeg in the builder stage but try to use it in another stage later. Can you share the full Dockerfile?

Comment: I have shared my full Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` in the `builder` stage. This means those tools are not available in the final image.

To fix your issue install these tools in your final stage like:

```
FROM node:18-slim as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/ai_api_builder/

COPY package*.json tsconfig.json /usr/src/ai_api_builder/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install mariadb-client -y && \
    npm install && npm cache clean --force

COPY ${REPO_DIR}/ ./

RUN npm run build && mv audio_store node_modules dist/

FROM node:18-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt install ffmpeg -y && \
    ffmpeg -version && \
    ffprobe -version

# Create and cd into app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/dwt_api_app/dist

# Copy the artifact to the new image
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/dwt_api_builder/dist ./

EXPOSE 3001
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "app.js"]
```

More about [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/).

Comment: thanks you, it't work. Can I install ffmpeg in stage 1 and copy it into stage 2 to opptimize image size?

Comment: You can, but IMHO it won't make much sense as you don't optimize image size that way.